# Помогите с разбором задачи на рекурсию

Tags: c++, рекурсия, олимпиада

> Между городом A и гоордом B проложена единственная дорога, на которой
>   построено N остановочных пунктов. Обычный автобусный маршрут из A в B
>   предусматривает остановки на каждом из оборудованных пунктов.
>   Экспрессный маршрут пропускает некоторые (не менее одного)
>   остановочные пункты, но ни один экспрессный маршрут не пропускает
>   более двух пунктов подряд. Сколько различных экспрессных маршрутов
>   можно организовать между городами A и B? Два маршрута считаются
>   различными, если множества остановочных пунктов, которые они
>   пропускают, различны. 1 <= N <= 70.

Решение такое: Пусть D(n) число всех маршрутов (обычных и экспрессных), соединяющих города A и B при условии n промежуточных остановок. Тогда ответ равен D(n) - 1. Рекуррентное соотношение для нахождения D(n): D(n) = D(n-1) + D(n-2) + D(n - 3). Обьясните пожалуйста, откуда взялась эта формула, по рекурсии задач не решал, так что максимально по-простому.

Comment: Вопрос не соответствует теме сайта

Comment: Возможно, этот сайт больше подойдёт для Вашего вопроса: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @V-Mor Почему это не соответствует??

Comment: @MBo Эта задача – математическая в чистом виде. Здесь нет ни капли программирования, а метка `C++` явно лишняя.

Comment: @MBo Тем более этот тип задач не содержится в справке в разделе "Какие вопросы можно задавать?"

Answer (score 1):

Как можно попасть на последнюю (n-ю) остановку? Приехав с предпоследней (n-1)-ой, с (n-2)-й, пропустив одну, или с (n-3)-й, пропустив две.

Вот и получается, что число возможных маршрутов складывается из D(n-1), D(n-2), D(n-3).

Как найти D(n-1)? Да по аналогии, как сумму D(n-2), D(n-3), D(n-4).

Применяя такие правила к каждой, можно получить рекурсивное решение.

Стоит отметить, что простая реализация неэффективна, т.к. одни и те же значения рассчитываются многократно. Поэтому с указанными ограничениями (N=70) при использовании рекурсии нужно **запоминать** посчитанные значения в массиве.

Кроме того, есть ещё более продвинутые методы расчёта, о них можно почитать в статьях о числах Фибоначчи (в данном случае т.н. числа трибоначчи)

Comment: идею вроде как понял, но возник еще один вопрос. Зачем они соеденили экспрессные и обычные маршруты?. Почему нельзя составить рекуррентную формулу для F(x) - кол-ва только экспрессных маршрутов?

Comment: Экспрессным же маршрут считается, если хотя бы один перескок есть. `ответ равен D(n) - 1` как раз из-за этого - считаются все маршруты, потом исключается единственный обычный.

Comment: т.е. это сложно (или невозможно) проверить есть ли перескок в случае D(n) - кол-во только экспресс маршрутов?

Comment: Скорее нерационально. когда вас (например) просят посчитать сумму всех натуральных чисел до `n` кроме 11, вы не станете выводить новую формулу, а просто возьмете `n * (n + 1) / 2 - (n >= 11 ? 11 : 0)`

Comment: Сложнее - например, придётся до самого дна рекурсии вести учёт  - был ли перескок в данной ветви рекурсии, а в результате всей этой бухгалтерии всего один маршрут будет признан негодным. extrn прав - это нерационально.